# Constructors and operators in c++ - not working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++ and I don't understand why the following code is not working:

```
class String
{
public:
    String();
    String(const String& other);
    String& operator = (const String& other);
    String& operator = (const wchar_t* other);
    String& operator () (const wchar_t* other);
    ~String();
    operator const wchar_t* ();
            ...
```

Somewhere in the main function:

```
wchar_t* x = L"A test string";
String y = (String)x; //not working
String z = x;  //not working
```

The VC++ compiler tells me this:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'wchar_t *' to 'String'   
Error   2   error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'wchar_t *' to 'String'    
IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "wchar_t *" to "String"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You need a constructor for `wchar_t*`.

```
String(const wchar_t*);
```

Comment: To elaborate: an assignment operator is insufficient. That would only be for assignment (`String y; y = x;`). Initialisation isn't assignment, even though it uses the same `=` symbol.

Answer (score 3):

None of the three lines "somewhere in main" use assignment, so
we can ignore any assignment operators you might have defined.
And you haven't defined a converting constructor, which takes a
single argument (a `wchar_t const*`), to convert your `wchar_t
const*`.